# How to build access point (from internet into local network) using RPI?

Tags: networking, linux, ethernet, port-forwarding

I need to be able to connect over ssh to my machines that are in local network where they do not have publick internet access.

I have RPI, yota usb lte router, linux on rpi board, local connection of rpi over ethernet.

Have tried to connect RPI to lan and wifi networks together. In  hostname i saw multiple IP addresses from these two networks. But they have priority that is setup somehow (iptables i guess).

Now i need to connect ethernet connection and usb router yota, to be able to connect from internet into intranet machine.

How to build this complex access piont to be able to connect over ssh into RPI and go forward to the ip address inside local network ?

Maybe port forwarding + some soft to get inside rpi nneded?

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is a VPN-Server. L2TP would be what you want as the much simpler PPTP is no longer supported by newer devices. I have a RPi running at home for exactly this purpose. I can access any device in my home network remotely from my MacBook Pro, iPhone and Windows 10.

There is a fairly easy setup script for that on [github](https://gist.github.com/jhenkens/11190151).

Read everything carefully before you do something.